# how to handle NetworkImage GET errors?

Tags: dart, flutter

how to handle the NetworkImage error if the URL is not exists or any error came from the request.

Ps. i don't plan to do double request one using the http package and then fetch it by second call i am looking for error handling through the NetworkImage widget itself

Comment: use cache_network_image package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: i used the package i managed to do a call on error but still getting flutter un caught exceptions

Comment: what do you mean? could you add some code ?

Comment: i am using the errorListener to perform some handling on errors but the console still through this error  ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following message was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Couldn't download or retreive file.
flutter:
flutter: Image provider:
flutter: CachedNetworkImageProvider("http://.........../api/sdfdsf?filename=Emp-20181127111943-صور.png&type=jpeg",

Comment: I am getting the same error "The following message was thrown resolving an image codec: flutter: Couldn't download or retreive file" even when errorWidget and errorListener is set.

Comment: There is an open issue for that problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118586#issuecomment-1450474036

Unfortunately no update since January 25...

Answer (score 0):

For [Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) or [Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) Just use errorBuilder.

```
Image.network('Your image url...',
        errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
            return Text('Your error widget...');
        },
    ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html

Comment: The question is referring to NetworkImage not Image.network

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cached_network_image** package it's very easy to handle network image error and it cached the image

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

**Here is an example:**

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl:'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/micah/:Sammrafi.png?size=128&background=%23FFFFFF',
                placeholder: (context, url) => const SizedBox.shrink(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage('https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/micah/:Samm.png?size=128&background=%23FFFFFF'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: What is to be done if I need an `ImageProvider` rather than an `Image` ?